# How to allow send kystrokes via terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I need to make some keystrokes using applescript and I need to do this on several machines. To execute keystroke, I have to allow this on accesebility settings:
[image]

I cannot go to each machine and allow this option in manual mode. So, I want to allow this programmatically, using my configuration in ansible. I've found some options look like what I need:

```
defaults read com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning
{
    "1::/Applications/Utilities" = 1;
    "1::/Applications/Utilities/Script Editor.app" = 1;
}
```

but changing value of `Applications/Utilities/Script Editor.app` is not helping:

```
defaults write com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning "1::/Applications/Utilities/Script Editor.app" 1
```

or

```
defaults write com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning "1::/Applications/Utilities/Script Editor.app" true
```

Script editor checkbox still being blanked even after machine reboot. How can I enable this checkbox via terminal command or some another programmatically way?

Comment: I hope you won't be able to do this without GUI scripting and knowledge of the end-user password. If you were to make the final decision for the end user, then the improved security of the Mac would not be worth the price. Also, I am sure that your question is tortuous, and you want to give full control not to Script Editor. Downvote from me.

Comment: > you want to give full control not to Script Editor

Nice, you caught me, I'm a hacker, who asking about hacking on the stackoverflow(sarcasm).
Actually, this is about remote administration. The point is that I have password from remote machine and I have sudo, but I have no idea how to enable accesability programmatically, but I can do it manually. If you really want to know why I need to give control to Script Editor, you can read my previous questions.

Comment: The **.plist** _file_ you are targeting has nothing to do with being able to give an _application_ privileges in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**, it merely shows the current state. The actual permissions are stored in the **TCC.db** _database_ and it's this _database_ that would need to be manipulated to do it from the _command line_, however, that too is no longer directly doable in **macOS** unless the system is enrolled in an [**MDM** program](https://www.apple.com/business/it/).

Comment: Well, you are also executing the script on a remote computers. If the script was executed by end users, then it would be possible to shift the manual part to them. But when executing a script on a remote computers, you yourself are the end user. So checking the checkbox manual work goes to you.

Comment: As a side note, when using `defaults` to set the _value_ of a _key_, one first needs to know what _type_ it is, a _string_, _integer_, _boolean_, etc. Knowing this in your use case would not have mattered as modifying that **.plist** _file_ would not have fixed your issue.  That said, in that **.plist** _file_ the _value_ of the _keys_ are _boolean_, so `defaults write domain key -bool TRUE` is the proper _syntax_. In **Terminal**: `man defaults`. -- Opening the **.plist** _file_ in **Xcode** or viewing its **XML** format, using e.g.: `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c print /path/to/file.plist`

Comment: > "The actual permissions are stored in the TCC.db" 
Thanks, I've found information about TCC and SIP. Seems like there is no way other to disable SIP and make changes in TCC.db

Comment: > "So checking the checkbox manual work goes to you."
Very nice, but these remote computers are for autotesting, not for real users.

Comment: Do you have **Remote Desktop** _type_ capabilities? If yes, then you could use **UI Scripting** to tick the _checkbox_.